How can i overcome this context "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"?
While retrieving data from MongoDB following error
**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

"at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverter1Byte.toOracleStringWithReplacement(CharacterConverter1Byte.java:531)
at oracle.sql.CharacterSetWithConverter.convertWithReplacement(CharacterSetWithConverter.java:200)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:770)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DBConversion.javaCharsToCHARBytes(DBConversion.java:711)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIClob.write(T4C8TTIClob.java:384)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.putChars(T4CConnection.java:2708)
at oracle.sql.CLOB.putChars(CLOB.java:408)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleClobWriter.write(OracleClobWriter.java:111)
at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:220)"

Version of Java - java version "1.8.0_401"
Netbean Version "8.2"
Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this error shall be highly appreciated

Please read How to Ask then [edit] the question to improve it and to add a [mre].

You say "while retrieving data from MongoDB" but the stacktrace shows you're running out of memory while calling FileCopyUtils.copy which has nothing to do with MongoDB. Look at the stack trace and see what you might be doing at the point where you call FileCopyUtils.copy. Also, there are tools like Eclipse Memory Analyzer that might help.

Just launch your app/server with increased heap size via -Xmx argument, see abovelinked duplicate (alternatives in your specific case are to limit upload/generated file sizes and return error to user, and/or save files in file system instead of DB but that speaks for itself)

@k314159 the stacktrace also shows the Oracle JDBC driver.
